# Pip install fails to install dependency when setup.py not in root directory

Tags: python, git, pip, setup.py, requirements.txt

I have a main github repo with several packages defined in it:

```
company_name
|
--- package1
|       |
|        ----- setup.py
|
--- package 2
        |
         ----- setup.py
```

Now I am trying to install and import package1 in another repo.
The problem I have is that I can only specify the git repo location in requirements.txt and then I am doing a

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

which fails because it complains it cannot find a setup.py file.

Does anyone has a solution for that? How can I specify the location of the setup.py files that are located in subdirectories?

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#examples) this can be done for an "editable" install:

```
$ pip install -e "git+https://git.repo/some_repo.git#egg=subdir&subdirectory=subdir_path" # install a python package from a repo subdirectory
```

It's not clear from the documentation whether it can *only* be done for editable or also for non-editable installs.

Comment: Awesome. I don't know how I missed that in the doc. Need to make sure though that I can also deploy it and it is not only for editable.